# Password parameters using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to establish password parameters to be 8-20 characters long, at least one upper case character, number, and symbol.  I have written the code as such

```
  (preg_match ('/^(\W+)(\d+)([A-Z]+)([a-z]+){8,20}$/', $_POST['pass1']) )
```

My interpretation of my code is as follows:

```
W+   one or more symbols (non alpha numeric)
d+   one or more numbers
[A-Z]+  one or more uppercase characters
[a-z]+  one or more lower case characters
{8,20}  string length min 8 max 20
```

When I enter the password as Anyhelp4me!  I get an invalid password message.  What are your suggestions.

Comment: And the interpretation of regex101: https://regex101.com/r/fR4xG1/1

Comment: What is the purpose to limit password length? Is having 21 character password a security sin or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't do it all with one regex.**  It will be far more maintainable, understandable, and easier to change in the future if you make multiple calls to preg_match with multiple regexes.

```
$password_is_ok =
    preg_match( '/\W/', $pass ) &&
    preg_match( '/\d/', $pass ) &&
    preg_match( '/[a-z]/', $pass ) &&
    preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $pass ) &&
    strlen( $pass ) >= 8 &&
    strlen( $pass ) <= 20;
```

That is far more readable and understandable by the next person who has to read your code (who might be you) than any single-regex monstrosity you can concoct.

Comment: Excellent suggestion...it is more "readable" and understandable

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I tried the previous recommendation and it only imposed the "8,10" restriction.  I found this on stackoverflow "Create preg_match for password validation allowing (!@#$%)" and modified the code presented in that response as follows:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\W)[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,20}$/
```

I have tested it several times and it does work.  You have to have at least one digit, one uppercase, one lower case and a specified symbol (!@#$%) and between 8 and 20 characters.